# R - using rbind on a dataframe of dataframes

Tags: json, r

I am running into a bit of an issue with this:

```
> dput(df1)

structure(list(`1` = structure(list(type = c("Player", "Player", 
"Player"), value = c(2980668L, 2980676L, 2980670L)), .Names = c("type", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(
    type = c("Player", NA, "Player"), value = c(NA, NA, 419405L
    )), .Names = c("type", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"), 
    `26` = structure(list(type = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), value = structure(list(coordinates = structure(list(
        x = c(0.90043921853644, NA, NA), y = c(0.40441176470588, 
        NA, NA)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"), 
        region = c(2L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("coordinates", "region"
    ), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("type", 
    "value"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"), `36` = structure(list(
        type = c(NA, NA, NA), value = c("Unknown", NA, NA)), .Names = c("type", 
    "value"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("1", 
"2", "26", "36"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("200001", 
"200002", "200003"))


> dput(df2)
structure(list(`1` = structure(list(type = c("Player", "Player", 
"Player"), value = c(2980668L, 2980676L, 2980670L)), .Names = c("type", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(
    type = c("Player", NA, "Player"), value = c(NA, NA, 419405L
    )), .Names = c("type", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"), 
    `26` = structure(list(type = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), value = structure(list(coordinates = structure(list(
        x = c(0.90043921853644, NA, NA), y = c(0.40441176470588, 
        NA, NA)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"), 
        region = c(2L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("coordinates", "region"
    ), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("type", 
    "value"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"), `36` = structure(list(
        type = c(NA, NA, NA), value = c("Unknown", NA, NA)), .Names = c("type", 
    "value"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("1", 
"2", "26", "36"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("200004", 
"200005", "200006")).
```

These are examples dataframes I am trying to `rbind()` together. In the case of this example, everything is the same between the two other than the rownames. I get the following errors when I try to run `rbind()` on the two:

```
> rbind(temp, temp2)
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’
```

Any thoughts on how I can make this `rbind()` work would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try `rbind(temp, temp2, make.row.names = TRUE)` or `rbind(temp, temp2, make.row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: thanks, but no luck with either of those suggestions

Comment: This structure is quite awkward. I'd suggest extracting inner data.frames into a single data.frame before the `rbind`

Comment: Yes i agree, that's what i've decided to do over the last few minutes - the original structure was the result of reading a large number of JSONs using fromJSON()

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to join all the original JSONs together, then extract the data from there

```
library(jsonlite)
json1 <- toJSON(df1)
json2 <- toJSON(df2)

df <- fromJSON(paste(substr(json1, 1, nchar(json1)-1 ),substr(json2, 2, nchar(json2)), sep = ","))
df
# 1.type 1.value 2.type 2.value 26.value.coordinates.x 26.value.coordinates.y 26.value.region   value
# 1 Player 2980668 Player      NA                 0.9004                 0.4044               2 Unknown
# 2 Player 2980676   <NA>      NA                     NA                     NA              NA    <NA>
# 3 Player 2980670 Player  419405                     NA                     NA              NA    <NA>
# 4 Player 2980668 Player      NA                 0.9004                 0.4044               2 Unknown
# 5 Player 2980676   <NA>      NA                     NA                     NA              NA    <NA>
# 6 Player 2980670 Player  419405                     NA                     NA              NA    <NA>
```